# How to build SQL query selecting not related items for many-to-many relation in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, many-to-many

I have **Coder** and **Programming language** entities with many-to-many relation. DB structure looks like:

```
coder
  - id (primary key)
  - name

proglang
  - id (primary key)
  - name

coder_to_proglang
  - id (primary key)
  - coder_id (foreign key for coder table)
  - proglang_id (foreign key for proglang table)
```

The question is how to select programming languages **not known** by a specific coder?

My best SQL query was:

```sql
select p.*, c.id as coder_id
from "proglang" as "p"
         left join "coder_to_proglang" as "j" on "p"."id" = "j"."proglang_id"
         left join "coder" as "c" on "c"."id" = "j"."coder_id"
where j.id is null or c.id != :coderId
```

I was thinking like this: unknown language is the language that is not linked via a junction table with a coder, so junction table ID can be **NULL**, or also that language can have a link with different coders. But this doesn't work because other coders can know the same language(s) that are known by a given coder.

I also suspect that we can use some joining to achieve subtraction of a set of known languages from a set of all existing languages, but cannot figure out how to describe this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a combination of all languages (using `cross join`) and codes; then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select c.name as coder, p.name as language
from proglang p cross join
     coder c left join
     coder_to_proglang cp
     on cp.proglang_id = p.id and cp.coder_id = c.id
where cp.coder_id is null;
```

Comment: Thank you again, that works great. Maybe you can advise some resource(s) well explaining joins in some not too difficult manner?